# Помогите понять отрывок кода

Tags: javascript

```
if (!checks[i](arguments[i])) {
     alert( "Некорректный тип аргумента номер " + i );
     return;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если переменная `checksi` имеет значение `false`, `0`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `null` или `""` вывести сообщение: "Некорректный тип аргумента номер", добавив в него конкатенацией значение переменной `i`.

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Если checksi не существует, то выдаем сообщение  "Некорректный тип аргумента номер " и номер (который в i)

Answer (score 0):

Приходится додумываться:

Предположительно, внешний код типа такого:

```
function some(){
 for(let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
  if (!checks[i](arguments[i])) {
      alert( "Некорректный тип аргумента номер " + i );
      return;
  }
 }
}
```

Это предполагает что есть объект `checks`, у которого ключи сделаны так: `0: function(e){...}, 1: function(e){...}, ...`.
Цикл проходит по всем аргументам, вызывая у `checks` поочерёдно его числовые методы, передавая туда очередной новый аргумент функции; если вызов вернёт `false` (или его представление), произойдёт `alert` и выход из функции `some`.
Например:
`some('hello', 'world')` приведёт к вызову `checks[0]('hello')` и `checks[1]('world')`.

Это коряво и глупо, не пользуйтесь подобным.

Comment: это может быть и массив методов, а не только объект :)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, а Вы наблюдательны и правы, сэр! Только `Array` - это частный случай объекта. В любом случае, выходит одно и то же, лучше эта проверка не становиться.